# Best way to get template variables from an external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

This is what I am currently doing to transfer a django template variable to a JS variable:

```
<input type="hidden" id="django_var" value="{{variable}}" />
...
var unique_var = $('#django_var').val();
```

Is there a more straightforward way to do this in the template, something that would work outside of forms as well? Thank you.

**Update**: the js variable will be an external file to the template, and thus won't be able to directly call the django template vars.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your HTML template header:

```
<script>
var my_var = "{{ django_var }}";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/my_script.js"></script>
```

The important thing to note is that you define your JS variables in the head before you include your javascript file.

Then in your javascript you can access $my_var

Answer (score 16):

Instead of adding hidden meta fields in the template, you add a little bit of inline Javascript in the template:

```
<script>
var MyGlobal = {
  var_1: {{var_1}},
  var_2: {{var_2}},
};
</script>
```

Later, in an external JS file, you can do:

```
var unique_var = MyGlobal.var_2;
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to set the value of a hidden form field and potentially other functions.

Comment: @David542: Updated answer. Basically, you can't transfer a template variable without using a template, except maybe by doing an additional AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes its cleaner to not create a whole bunch of global vars, you can pass them as params to the js file like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/my_script.js?param1=xyz&amp;param2=abc"></script>
```

Within your external js you can easily write a method to parse these params.