# How to use django tags in External js file.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I want to append the chat popup in the html body from Jquery when the element gets clicked and then I want to show the messages from the database.

Following is my code in an external js File,

```
chatPopup = '<div class="message_box" style="right:290px" rel="'+ userID+'"><div class="message_header" rel="'+ userID+'">'+
            '<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000'+pro+'"  class="user_icon"><h3 class="username">'+username+'</h3>'+
            '<i class="fa fa-times close" rel="'+ userID+'"></i></div><hr><div class="message_content"><div class="messages" rel="'+ userID+'">'+
            '{% for chat in thread.chatmessage_thread.all %}'+
            '<div class="chat">'+
            '{% if chat.user == user %}'+
            '<div class="new_messages p2">{{ chat.message }}</div>'+
            '{% else %}'+
            '<div class="new_messages p1">{{ chat.message }}</div>'+
            '{% endif %}</div>{% endfor %}</div><div class="input_box">'+
            '<textarea type="text" class="message_input" rel="'+ userID+'" placeholder="Type Message..."></textarea>'+
            '<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right enter" rel="'+ userID+'"></i></div></div></div>';   
            if ( $('[rel="'+userID+'"]').length == 0) {
                $("body").append(  chatPopup  );
```

What I know that we can't use the Django tags other than .html files, But is there any way how to send Django variable `thread.chatmessage_thread.all` (<model_name><related_name>all) look like variable in external file using the trick used in the following answer in link?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7318511/14715170

Comment: You can create a seprate **HTML** file named as `chatPopup.html` and add all django html code in that file and then inside javascript use ajax to get that html rendered from backend

Comment: Can you please elaborate it ?

Comment: *I want to append the chat popup in the html body from Jquery when the element gets clicked and then I want to show the messages from the database.* - **If you're trying to fetch data from backend then either you can add html inside your javascript like you did in your question**

Comment: Or you can fetch whole rendered html from backend by making ajax call everytime when user clicks